# Reversing dictionary is separating string characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary with key-value pairs identical:

```
d = {'SEX': 'SEX', 'F': 'F', 'M': 'M', 'U': 'U', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED': 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'}
```

Eventually, it will have additional values associated with keys (i.e., `'M': ['M','MALE']`), but I am starting with the simplest case above first.

I next need to reverse the dictionary. For the simple example d, d=reverse_d. In the future with `'M': ['M','MALE']`, I would get `'M':'M', 'MALE':'M'`.

When I try to reverse the simple case of d; however, I get the individual characters of values in the dictionary creating separate keys:

```
reverse_d = {'S': ['SEX'], 'E': ['SEX', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'X': ['SEX'], 'F': ['F', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'M': ['M'], 'U': ['U', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'N': ['UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'D': ['UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'I': ['UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'R': ['UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'T': ['UNDIFFERENTIATED', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'], 'A': ['UNDIFFERENTIATED']}
```

Here is the code I used to reverse it:

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()

    for key in d:
        for item in d[key]:
            if item not in inverse:
                inverse[item] = [key]
            else:
                inverse[item].append(key)

    return inverse
```

Comment: start by making all values lists now. it will make your life much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check if the value is a `list` then get the items otherwise you will get characters:

```
d = {'SEX': 'SEX', 'F': 'F', 'M': ['M', 'MALE'], 'U': 'U', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED': 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'}

reversed_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for item in v:
            reversed_d[item] = k
    else:
        reversed_d[v] = k

print(reversed_d)
```

output :

```
{'SEX': 'SEX', 'F': 'F', 'M': 'M', 'MALE': 'M', 'U': 'U', 'UNDIFFERENTIATED': 'UNDIFFERENTIATED'}
```

Comment: Brian, it's also probably a good idea to make all the values lists to begin with.  It might seem verbose or unnecessary to have lists of 1 item, but it allows you to not have to do checks like this.  `{'M': ['M'], 'F': ['F'], ...}`

Comment: @KyleParsons Great, that's the other option.

Comment: @KyleParsons, this was the first thing I tried, but I must be doing it wrong as it doesn't return values as list objects. What do I need to do to implement values as list to the following? ```d = dict(zip(dfSENDCodelist['CDISC Submission Value'], dfSENDCodelist['CDISC Submission Value']))```